# Why is $MOD_{p^k}P=MOD_pP$ at every prime $p$?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

[Complexity zoo](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:M#modkp) states that $MOD_{2^k}P=MOD_2P$.

It is clear that if $MOD_2P$ accepts (number of accepting paths is off) then $MOD_{2^k}P$ accepts.

Why is it clear that if $MOD_2P$ rejects (number of accepting paths is even ) then $MOD_{2^k}P$ rejects?

Does $MOD_{2^k}P=MOD_2P$ have a different interpretation? I mean somehow we can construct a $MOD_{2^k}P$ machine from a $MOD_2P$ machine at every $k\in\Bbb N$?

I am interested in when $k$ is polynomial in input length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct interpretation is: a problem belongs to $MOD_2 P$ if and only if it belongs to $MOD_{2^k} P$.

Equivalently, a language is accepted by some $MOD_2 P$ machine if and only if it is accepted by some $MOD_{2^k} P$ machine. It doesn't have to be the same machine.

The way you prove these equivalences is through identities like this:

- $x \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$ iff $2x \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$.
- $x \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$ iff $1+(x+1)(\frac{x(x+1)}{2}+1) \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$.

I'll let you work this out.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70829/discussion-on-answer-by-yuval-filmus-why-is-mod-pkpmod-pp-at-every-prime).